# URLs for products are broken in VirtoCommerce

Tags: virtocommerce

The links to the collections (categories) work fine but when I click on any product in any collection, the link broken. That's because the application name is repeated twice in the url. Example: 
http://localhost/VirtoCommerce/VirtoCommerce/products/v-b0035eg04i

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to site installed in virtual directory. Try setting up the site in the root, like demo2.virtocommerce.com. We are still working on correct routing for the frontend demo site, as it needs to generate SEO friendly URL based on keywords specified in admin, but it still should work for the root site.

Comment: I have another site in the root. All URLs should be relative to where the app is installed. Some sites might install the store under a child folder and the store is not the main site.

Comment: You can create a second root site in IIS and add custom host name for it to work, or you can use IIS express from within visual studio. There is also such limitation as certain themes don't support not root site due to them having links like this "<a hred="/products">...". That said, we still working on new routing engine for frontend.